# Copying a single file into .jar with a different name using the Gradle task "jar"

Tags: gradle, jar, build.gradle

How can I copy a single file into .jar with a different name using the Gradle task "jar"?

For example

local:src/main/resources/mypkg_prod.properties → jar-file:/mypkg.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the file into the jar and then do a rename.

This is a link to some information on the rename method from the Gradle docs:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:renaming_files

Example:

```
jar {
    from 'my_file.txt'
    rename 'my_file.txt', 'my_super_file.txt'
}
```

**Note:** If your file is already being included in the jar, just add the rename line to the jar task:

```
jar {
    rename 'mypkg_prod.properties', 'mypkg.properties'
}
```